# How to generate new hashtable during a for loop in the Arraylist of hashtable

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

Edited, more clarification. 
Hi sorry for the vague question, by problems creating a new hashtable, i mean Adding New rows.

Previously, if i know how many rows i wanted to add example i wanted to add 3 rows, i will declare 3 hashmap and input the value as shown below. However for now, i wanted to do some calulation, and generate x amount of row based on the calculation as shown. I do not know how to declare and create a new row/hashmap in the for loop.

```
protected void populateList(int i,Double profit,Double balance, Double revenue)
{
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap row1 = new HashMap();
    row1.put(FIRST_COLUMN,i);
    row1.put(SECOND_COLUMN, balance);
    list.add(row1);

    HashMap row2 = new HashMap();
    row2.put(FIRST_COLUMN,i);
    row2.put(SECOND_COLUMN, balance);
    list.add(row2);

    HashMap row3 = new HashMap();
    row3.put(FIRST_COLUMN,i);
    row3.put(SECOND_COLUMN, balance);
    list.add(row3);
}
```

I want to create a list view with multiple columns and dynamically churn out rows through a calculation when you click on a button. So i created an arraylist of hashtable(rows of individual hashtables), however i have problems creating a new hashtable.

Under **onClick**

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    for (int i=1; i <= count; i++) {
        // figure to be input into column
        Double profit = totalsum - cost;
        Double balance = totalsum - profit - cost;
        Double revenue = total sum;

        populateList(i,profit,balance,revenue);
    }
}
```

**populateList** method

```
protected void populateList(int i,Double profit,Double balance, Double revenue)
{
    list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    HashMap temp = new HashMap();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN,i);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, balance);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, profit);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, revenue);
    list.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: `i have problems creating a new hashtable` what problem you have?

Comment: In `populateList()`: `list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();` -- You are creating a new, empty list for every line, discarding any previous entries. Create the list *once* and then add those `HashMap`s to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
    for (int i=1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // figure to be input into column
        Double profit = totalsum - cost;
        Double balance = totalsum - profit - cost;
        Double revenue = total sum;

        list.add(populatelist(i,profit,balance,revenue));


    }
}

protected HashMap populatelist(int i,Double profit,Double balance, Double revenue) {
    HashMap temp = new HashMap();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN,i);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, balance);
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, profit);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, revenue);
    return temp;

}
```

But hard to say with what you gave.

Comment: `Void` and `return` ?

Comment: Let's not be too cryptic! The return type for `populateList()` should be `HashMap` ... a simple oversight, I'd say.

Comment: it was a copy/paste hint on what he was trying to do. didn't doublecheck. my bad.